# Django database inputs not being validated

Tags: django, django-models

I have this class:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    value=models.IntegerFiled(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

I get user input for the value attribute, create an object according to the user input and save it to the database. The problem is that the user can enter e.g. 120 in the form that is used to get the input from the template/html-page to the view's method. Then an invalid object is saved to the database.
How exactly does the MaxValueValidator work? When does it do anything? What purpose do validators serve?( I really couldn't find any answer to my questions in the documentation)

I do check if the input form is valid in the view, but this doesn't seem to prevent saving invalid objects by just changing the HTML attributes in the form via developer tools in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) to generate your form from the model if you want your validators to be run automatically. As per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

Answer (score 1):

[Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators) work with [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/)

You can make a form, such as

```
class ObjectForm(forms.Form):
    value = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

Then validate the form based on user input

```
if ObjectForm(request.POST).is_valid():
    # save model object here
```

Hope this helps.